# Create a list of the date/datetime variable in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, date, pandas

def date_ranges(data):
    _temp = data.dtypes
    return _temp == intI want to get a list of all the variables in my pandas dataset that are of date or datetime data types.

If I had a 100 column dataset and 12 different date or datetime fields I would want it to give me a list of those 12 column names.

```
output = ['Datefield1','Datetimefield2','Datedeltafield3',.......]
```

I can generate a boolean list for integer variables but I don't know how to check for date dtype:

```
def date_ranges(data):
    _temp = data.dtypes
    return _temp == int

date_ranges(data)
```

Comment: have you tried isinstance?

Answer (score 0):

```
output = [col[0] for col in df.dtype if col[1] in (date, datetime)]
```

This is untested but should give you the general idea--just put whatever types you want on the right.

Comment: KeyError: 'There are no fields in dtype int64.'

Answer (score 0):

I think this worked.

```
def date_ranges(data):
    _temp = ['date' in str(n) for n in list(data.dtypes)]
    return _temp


date_ranges(data)
```